# Blackberry - System.out.println() using eclipse plugin

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am just entered into the Blackberry Arena..

I am using `Eclipse Plugin` for running my testing application to simulator.

So, In my code somewhere I have add `System.out.println("Print");` statements, but by debugging or running app to simulator, I couldn't find any log statements printed to eclipse console.

Is there anything that I need to take care for using `println()` methods ?

Comment: have you tried restarting the eclipse.coz sometimes when u change the simulator os then console does not displays any log information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it is not enough to "Run" your app, you have to "Debug" to see the output. Second you need to make sure your eclipse console is set to "BlackBerry Simulator Output Console".

Once you've done that you should be able to see a whole lot of log statements, most of them from BlackBerry but yours should be in there too.

Answer (score 2):

Run it in debug mode in the BlackBerry simulator.  It'll be there, unfortunately there will also be a ton of BlackBerry print statements mixed in.